# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For some reason, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` doesn't get called. I have included the main.m and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method below. Can someone help me out here.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSLog(@"Application works");

    return YES;

}
```

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"



int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

    }


}
```

Comment: are you trying to call this in UIViewController?

Comment: No. its in AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time it happened with me, because of Simulator was messed up.Resetting the iOS Simulator did the job for me,May be it helps you in the same way.To Reset your iOS Simulator:-

- Open Simulator
- Select iOS Simulator in Menu Bar
- Select **Reset Content and Settings**
  [image]

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you might need to add the

```
 - application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

method too.